# Property injection with Unity

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

i encoutered problem with unity, i want to use property injection, here is what i had in my code :
config of the container :

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<GTModelContainer, GTModelContainer>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<GTModelContainer>())
                 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkGT>()
                 .RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())                     
                 .RegisterType<ISocieteServices, SocieteServices>() ;
 }
```

SocieteService Class :

```
 public class SocieteServices : ISocieteServices
{
    private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    public SocieteServices(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

}
```

i tried to use property injection (i can't use constructor injection with custom data annotation) and here what i had done :

```
   public class CodeSocieteUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     [Dependency]
    public ISocieteServices SocieteService {get; set;} 

     [InjectionMethod]
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        string codeSociete = value as string;

        var societe = SocieteService.getSocieteByCode(codeSociete);
        if (societe == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        else return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

    }
}
```

the problem is that the societeService in CodeSocieteUniqueAttribute class is not injected.

Comment: Where do you resolve this attribute? An IoC container is not a magical tool that change the way the .NET runtime works. Attributes are create by the framework, not by an IoC container. So unless you explicitly tell Unity to `BuildUp` such attribute, nothing will happen.

Comment: i tried to resolve by doing that :  var container = new UnityContainer(); SocieteService = container.Resolve<ISocieteServices>(); but SocieteService stlii be null

Comment: You are not resolving the attribute: Unity doesn't know this attribute exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your class for registering types is publicly accessible and has a IUnityContainer object, ie:

```
public static class Resolver
{

    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // type registrations here
        container.RegisterType<GTModelContainer, GTModelContainer>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<GTModelContainer>())
             .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkGT>()
             .RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())                     
             .RegisterType<ISocieteServices, SocieteServices>() ;

        // Now, set the container
        Container = container;
    }
}
```

You could access the container you've built up and resolve these types during method execution.

For instance,

```
public class CodeSocieteUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     [Dependency]
    public ISocieteServices SocieteService { get; set; } 

     [InjectionMethod]
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var societeServices = Resolver.Container.Resolve<ISocieteServices>();
        SocieteService = societeServices; // Or, you know, just use this since it's resolved.
        string codeSociete = value as string;

        var societe = SocieteService.getSocieteByCode(codeSociete);
        if (societe == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        else return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

    }
}
```

This is actually pretty standard practice, and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx) describes resolving items during runtime.

Another option is to pop the resolution into a default constructor like this:

```
public class CodeSocieteUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public ISocieteServices SocieteService {get; set;} 
    public CodeSocieteUniqueAttribute()
    {
        var societeServices = Resolver.Container.Resolve<ISocieteServices>();
        SocieteService = societeServices; 
    }
     // the rest of the class omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: My Class for registering type is accessible but i don't have a IUnityContainer object accessible. And even though i create it in my class i can't resolve it.

Comment: Check the "Resolver" class now, I've made a few adjustments.  This would set the instance of the container which you can use to resolve against.